# Swagger UI watch security specifications

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am documenting an API with Swagger, is the first time I use Swagger. When I am using the swagger editor I am able to document and see what I want to see. However, when I put the same yaml file in the swagger ui, I am not able to see my security definitions. Could be that I am doing something wrong? or is just not possible?

```
securityDefinitions:
  clientId:
    type: apiKey
    name: x_client_id
    in: header
  accessToken:
    type: apiKey
    name: access_token
    in: header
security:
  - clientId: []
  - accessToken: []
```

And an example where I use

```
/auth/signup:
  post:
    description: register a user
    security:
     - accessToken: []
    parameters:
      - name: User
        in: body
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/UserRequest'
    responses:
      200:
        description: SuccessfulResponse
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/AuthSuccessfulResponse'
      400:
        description: Error
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/BadRequest'
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently yes, the security definitions are not enforced dynamically.  This will be resolved in a day or so when https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/pull/2014 is merged.